# Binding of subcontrol doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am using C# 7, .Net 4.7.2 and WPF 4.5.2

I want to display hierarichal data. Therefore I am using a ListBox as toplevel control and ListView as sublevel control. Regardless of any styles, the DataTemplate of the ListBox looks like this

```
<DataTemplate>

    <Border>

        <Grid>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"    />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"    />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty}" />
            <ListView   Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SubDataClasses}"
                                     ItemContainerStyle="{DynmicRessource MyListViewItem}" />

        </Grid>

    </Border>

</DataTemplate>
```

In the DataContext there's a property called MyDataSource to which the ItemsSource of the ListBox binds to. The Property looks like this

```
    public ObservableCollection<MyMainDataClass> MyDataSource { get; set; }
```

And last but not least the data classes:

```
    public class MySubDataClass
    {
        public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    }


    public class MyMainDataClass
    {
        public string SomeTextProperty { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<MySubDataClass> SubDataClasses { get; set; }

    }
```

The bindings in the ListBox work fine. But the *SomeTextProperty* happens to be displayed correctly. The number of *MySubDataClasses* belonging to each *MyMainDataClass* is correct as well.

But the content of *SomeValue* is never even diplayed at all. All you can see is name the of the class *MySubDataClass*. Usually, in this case there's a binding error, for example the name of the property in the binding is misspelled. Not in my case. But something has to be wrong, though.

I checked the binding with *diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High*. But the Output-Window of Visual Studio shows nothing at all. No infos, no warnings, no errors. There's absoluty nothing. The same tracing on the Binding of the ItemsSource of the ListBox shows everything correctly.

I also tried the ListView seperately in a test scenario. Works correctly. So there's nothing wrong with the ListView itself, but as subcontrol of the ListBox.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Addition:

The style of the ListViewItem look like this

```
<Style x:Key="MyListViewItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeValue}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Apparently there is no DataTemplate that is used for ListView's ItemTemplate. How do you expect the SomeValue property to be displayed? And just a note, why is it a ListView at all (which is more complex than a ListBox)? Do you set its View property? Do you need selection support? An ItemsControl might be a better choice.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the ListView itself works fine. So, the ItemContainerStyle is set properly. But just to be exact, I added the style definition of the ListViewItem to my original post. I do need a selection support an it is possible that I need somthing like the DataGrid RowDetails, too. But not right away. I chose the ListView because I thought it might be easier to handle in case multiple columns became necessary.

Comment: Despite the typo `DynmicRessource` why is the ItemsContainerStyle set as dynamic resource? And why do you set ItemContainerStyle instead of ItemTemplate? Even simpler would perhaps be an auto-selected DataTemplate with DataType set to MySubDataClass.

Comment: On your `ListView` have you tried using `DisplayMemberPath` to get that value displayed?

Comment: "*Usually, in this case there's a binding error*" is not correct. If you see only the class name that means that your ItemContainerStyle has not been applied at all, and the ListView uses the default ItemContainerStyle and ItemTemplate, where only the result of `MySubDataClass.ToString()` is shown.

Comment: I've just tried to use StaticRessource instead of DynamicRessource. There's no difference, I could recognize. The same thing happens when I use ItemTemplate instead of ItemContainerStyle. Please be aware, that this example is simplified. The real world ControlTemplate of the ListViewItem is much more complex and the currently used style for a single row will be chosen by a StyleSelector class. But the problem that I am facing is as simple as described.

Comment: It's obvious that you're showing a simplified example, because what you are showing here should just work. This way you are only attracting useless answers. Please try to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, your question can't be answered. My guess however would be that your StyleSelector just does not provide the expected Style. At least it seems obvious that no ItemContainerStyle is applied at all.

Answer (score -1):

I think the TextBox of ListViewItems should binding the property of MySubDataClass

```
<Style x:Key="MyListViewItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding MySubDataClass.XXXX}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is wrong. The DataContext of the ListViewItem is a MySubDataClass instance, hence `Text="{Binding SomeValue}"` is correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MyMainDataClass();
    }
}
public class MySubDataClass
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
public class MyMainDataClass
{
    public string SomeTextProperty { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MySubDataClass> SubDataClasses { get; set; }
    public MyMainDataClass()
    {
        SomeTextProperty = "test";
        SubDataClasses = new ObservableCollection<MySubDataClass>();
        SubDataClasses.Add(new MySubDataClass() { SomeValue = "test1" });
        SubDataClasses.Add(new MySubDataClass() { SomeValue = "test2" });
    }
}
```

code like this,it worked.the image is result.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cuw6.png)

Comment: I think you don't set its parent's DataContext

Comment: Please read the question again. OP *does* see the items in the inner ListView, just their ItemContainerStyle is not applied. This answer is as wrong as your other, and both should be deleted. Sorry, but this is not a place where people guess answers (like "I think"). Please only write an answer if you understand the problem, and *know* a solution.

Comment: Wrong is wrong.Wrong answer should be deleted.That's right.The answer of "their ItemContainerStyle is not applied" is you add a TextBox in ListViewItem's Template

Comment: That's what OP tries without success. Sorry, but you haven't understood the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your problem，but I really don't know what you want.

Comment: I just want to tell you that you did not understand the problem, hence your answer makes no sense and should be deleted. Just in case you didn't realize, I am not the one who asked the question.

Comment: So, what's the problem?I want to know where I'm wrong.

Comment: I already explained it in my first comment in this post: "*OP does see the items in the inner ListView, just their ItemContainerStyle is not applied*" - So the problem has nothing to do with setting any DataContexts, as this answer is suggesting (although you've removed any explanatory text from it).